# Port forwarding on MacOS Catalina to resolve DNS issues

Tags: safari, dns, voip, portforwarding, macos-catalina

I'm currently having intermittent issues with Safari loading web pages due to it's disagreements with my default DNS addresses. I can use custom DNS with no issues, aside from my VoIP application not connecting when I do switch my DNS. I've managed to identify the specific ports that are connecting to another set of specific ports and IP for the VoIP application, and I want to adjust my settings somewhere so that I can route those specific addresses.

Currently, to identify the addresses for the app, I type **sudo lsof -n -I TCP** in terminal and I can identify the app is using the following below:

- TCP 10.5.9.151:50036->xxx.xxx.x.xxx:https
- TCP 10.5.9.151:50094->192.168.5.173:5448
- TCP 10.5.9.151:50093->xxx.xxx.x.xxx:https
- TCP 10.5.9.151:50095->192.168.5.173:5448
- TCP 10.5.9.151:50098->192.168.5.173:5448
- TCP 10.5.9.151:50099->192.168.5.173:5448
- TCP 10.5.9.151:50100->192.168.5.173:5448

By default, three DNS addresses are loading in my preferences, all of them private/local network. If I manually add those three DNS addresses after manually adding Cloudflare's DNS, the VoIP will not connect. If I rearrange so that the Cloudflare DNS is last on the list, Safari reverts back to intermittent connection and the VoIP works fine.

I don't have this issue with Chrome, but I'd prefer to remain on Safari. If I have to go without the VoIP application, though it's handy to see who's calling as the phone is out of view in my normal workflow, it's not the end of the world. I'm marginally familiar with Terminal, but I don't know how to modify my hostfile without risking botching my computers network connection. Would be nice if there's a GUI solution that's free. I tried Core Tunnel but I kept getting connection refused messages, likely because of poor configuration on my part.